# Querying Pre-deployment Approval Groups for All Stages in TFS DevOps Releases Using API

Tags: azure-devops, tfs

I'm working with the TFS (DevOps) API and I'm trying to automate the process of ensuring that a specific group of approvers is added to the "Pre-deployment approvals" section under "Pre-deployment conditions" for every stage in each release. I want to achieve this programmatically through the API.

Could someone please guide me on how to achieve this using the TFS API? Specifically, I would like to know:

1. How can I retrieve the list of stages for each release in my project?
2. What API endpoints or methods should I use to access and modify the "Pre-deployment approvals" settings for each stage?

I've done some research and found some relevant API documentation, but I'm not entirely sure how to piece everything together for this specific scenario. Any code examples, pointers to relevant documentation, or guidance would be greatly appreciated.